# Missing Geocoded Addresses in Attribute Table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, geocoding, address

I have geocoded about 13,000 addresses. I opened the Interactive Rematch Window and made adjustments where necessary. When I look at the Interactive Rematch window, I can see all of my addresses.

However, when I open the associated shapefile's attribute table, I only see 1,550 addresses.  I know that sometimes ArcMap will truncate large data files, but that's not happening here.

Also I don't have any edits to save in the Interactive Rematch Window.

Am I missing a step that refreshes the shapefile or what?